# how to import jks file in visual studio 2019 as existing keystore

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, keystore

I want to update an App on Google Play. I lost the Keystore password, after contacting google support I followed the below-given commands, and they reset the upload key for me.

```
 1. keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks                 

 2. keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

Now I have the `keystore.jks` file. Now here Problem comes.

I am following these steps in Visual Studio 2019.

Right-click on `Myproject.Android > Archive` then getting apk file `Bundle Format: apk`

Click `Distribute > Google Play > Import`

then    [Import an Existing Keystore dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fVsN.png) it is expecting with an extension of `.keystore` file to import but I have `.jks` tried to convert it to `.keystore` as well but not succeded.

Here is the error I am getting

```
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.PublicationUtilities.KeyManagement.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<ImportKeyAsync>b__0(Task`1 t) in C:\A\1\34\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\PublicationUtilities\KeyManagement.cs:line 313
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Publishing.Presentation.ViewModels.AndroidImportKeyViewModel.<Import>d__48.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\34\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Publishing\Presentation\ViewModels\AndroidImportKeyViewModel.cs:line 133
```

Is there anything I am missing?

How I can use `keystore.jks` to update my App?

Comment: AFAIK jks and keystore are the same thing and you should be able to simply rename it.  "tried to convert it to .keystore as well but not succeded." - what **exactly** did you do to convert it?

Comment: @Jason I found an article they recommend this command keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore c:\temp2\h2vkeystore.jks -destkeystore c:\temp2\h2vkeystore.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12
orignally it was keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore c:\temp2\h2vkeystore.jks -destkeystore c:\temp2\h2vkeystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12

Comment: did you try simply renaming the file?

Comment: @Jason no i can try now

Comment: @Jason renamed the extension with .keystore and used the same password and Alias.
and I get the same above mentioned error in the question.

Comment: I think you can contact the google support for further support.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Actually I solved the problem. I was missing one step  zipalign step

Comment: Congrats. Thanks for your support for xamarin. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I should post how I resolved this issue if someone else would be facing this issue he might solve it by following these steps.

After getting `keystore.jks` file copy your `project.Android.apk` and `keystore.jks` files to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\30.0.2` location.

run Command Prompt as administrator in given location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\30.0.2`

Now you need to `zipalign` the apk file manually, run the following commands.

```
run zipalign -v -p 4 com.project.Android.apk com.projectAligned.Android.apk
```

then you have to sign apk.

```
apksigner sign --ks keystore.jks --out com.projectRelease.Android.apk com.projectAligned.Android.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with the Visual Studio keystore import tool and it turns out the import tool requires a non-empty password for the alias as well as the keystore. Here's how you can copy the keystore.jks file to a new upload.keystore file with the alias password required by the import tool:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -srcalias upload -destkeystore upload.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12 -destalias upload -destkeypass password
```

Now you can use Visual Studio to import the newly created `upload.keystore` using the alias password you specified for `-destkeypass` above and use Visual Studio to sign as usual rather than signing from the command line.

Comment: This is the best solution for those of us using Visual Studio! As much as I like using the command line, it's a lot more practical to just finish your code, build, archive and send it directly to Google Play. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one app, and the easiest solution with Visual Studio was:

1. Create a new keystore file with Visual Studio, after that you can find it at:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore\alias\alias.keystore
```

2. Once you have the new key, use keytool to generate the certificate from that file:

   keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore alias.keystore

The new certificate (.pem) will be in the same folder, and the .keystore file works just as the .jks that Andoid Studio usually generates but it's better with Visual Studio. This way no realigning is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Visual Studio and none of the previous options worked:

I was facing this same error for an hour and I got to this post, it turns out that in my case the `Alias ​​Name` was incorrect and generating this error.
(I found out through the `.keystore` file name and opening it via notepad) so make sure also that Alias ​​name is correct